# Still include rows where no matching values found

Tags: c#, datatable

I have got 2 tables, one with the columns:

- ItemId
- Number
- Title
- CreatedDate
- LastModifiedDate

And the other one with the columns:

- ItemId
- Title
- ItemTitle

What I am trying to do is create a new datatable that clones the first one with the column "Function" added, the values for this column will come from the ItemTitle column from the 2nd dataTable.

I am doing this like so:

```
DataTable test = dtFinal.Clone();
test.Columns.Add("Function");

foreach (DataRow row in dtFinal.Rows)
{
    DataRow[] FunctionData = customPropertiesTable.Select(string.Format("ItemId='{0}' AND Title ='Function'", Convert.ToString(row["ItemId"])));

    if (FunctionData != null && FunctionData.Length > 0)
    {
        string detail = FunctionData[0]["ItemTitle"].ToString();
        var lst = row.ItemArray.ToList();
        lst.Add(detail);
        test.Rows.Add(lst.ToArray());

    }

}
```

Now this does work but it means that the new table will only show rows where that condition is met, what I would like to do is have it that the new table will still include the rows where the condition was not met so I could end with something like:

[image]

Where the function value of the row could be blank if the condition wasn't met. How could I update what I have done to do this?

Comment: Is there anything unclear about my question? Just wondering if it needs improvement to get interaction from people

Comment: There is too much information in your question and most of it is not related to the problem itself. It seems that you just don't know how to properly get data from DB. I'd suggest you to start with creating some simple DB and getting rows from its tables. Then try to execute more complex queries and get results. And when you get enough experience you can return to your problem.

Comment: It seems more a problem with writing a proper _else_ block. If the condition is met then do this else do that.

Comment: I had been assuming it was to do with that, but I'm not entirely sure on how to write it properly so it does what I'm looking for it to do

Comment: do you have any suggestions @Steve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this, it just simply needs to be:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dtFinal.Rows)
{
    DataRow[] FunctionData = customPropertiesTable.Select(string.Format("ItemId='{0}' AND Title ='Function'", Convert.ToString(row["ItemId"])));

if (FunctionData != null && FunctionData.Length > 0)
{
    string detail = FunctionData[0]["ItemTitle"].ToString();
    var lst = row.ItemArray.ToList();
    lst.Add(detail);
    test.Rows.Add(lst.ToArray());

}   else {
        string detail = "";
        var lst = row.ItemArray.ToList();
        lst.Add(detail);
        test.Rows.Add(lst.ToArray());
    }
```

}